# What does it mean when I'm trying to install pod files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, cocoapods

I just tried to install the SDK from https://github.com/fulldecent/FDWaveformView/blob/master/README.md

According to its instructions below, I need to install the pod files named `FDWaveformView`.

Here is what happens when I try to install it:

[image: git error]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: bcs your project already have one pod file so open and update pod.if you use code in github than only install pod bcs already create pod file in project

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial
      https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

it teaches you how to use cocoapods in iOS

Comment: thanks, and have checked it, but according to its instructions, there shouldn't be a problem like this.

Comment: since I did insert `use_frameworks!` in my pod file.